# Get email (username) in Claims azure ad b2c signed In with AzureAd like a Social account

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using starter pack of custom polices with the SocialAndLocalAccounts package to sign in with an Azure Active Directory account.

I customized the flows with custom attributes and it works well for me.
I need to receive the email used for the login (username = email).

In RelyingParty I have this OutputClaims

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId = "signInName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId = "signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType = "email" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId = "otherMails" />
```

When a user signs-in  with a local b2c account, I get the email
in "signInName" and "email" claims,
but when a user signs-in with an AzureAd account , the claims are empty.

How can I get the email?
How must I write the custom policies (TrustFrameworkBase and TFExtensions) ?

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Azure AD identity is signed-in with for the first time, you must map from the **upn** claim that is issued by Azure AD to the **email** claim that is used by Azure AD B2C, so that this **email** claim can be:

1. Written as the **otherMails** property in the **user** object to the Azure AD B2C directory.
2. Issued by Azure AD B2C in the ID token to the client application.

To map from the **upn** claim that is issued by Azure AD to the **email** claim that is used by Azure AD B2C, add a new `<OutputClaim />` to the Azure AD authentication technical profile:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>commonaad</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Common AAD</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Common-AAD">
      <DisplayName>Multi-Tenant AAD</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      ...
      <OutputClaims>
        ...
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
      </OutputClaims>
      ...
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

[The **AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId** technical profile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/a766d8c7e348365c16299e8e5603e05073d2dac5/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L564) converts the **email** claim to the **otherMails** claim by invoking [the **CreateOtherMailsFromEmail** claims transformation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/a766d8c7e348365c16299e8e5603e05073d2dac5/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L307) and then saves the **otherMails** claim to the **user** object.

To issue the **email** claim in the ID token to your client application, add a new `<OutputClaim />` to the relying party technical profile:

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    ...
    <OutputClaims>
      ...
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" PartnerClaimType="emails" />
    </OutputClaims>
    ...
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Comment: What's the "emails" in the last OutputClaim: PartnerClaimType="emails"?

Comment: For local Azure AD user this works: <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="upn" />, but federated user it requires <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />. How would I combine these for both to work? Now I just added them both and it seems to work, is this correct approach?

Comment: is the relying party PartnerClaimType intentionally "emails" instead of "email"?